# get value of dynamic enum

Tags: python, add-on, properties

I made dynamic enum for a preview and I would like to select a preview and then press a button for appending this object from another blend file.

But how do I get a value from a dynamic enum? Or is that possible? Or do I have to work arround that and do that an other way (which I dont know though)?

Help is very appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where is your enum?

please show some code in order to help you

Comment: It's just the dynamic enums from the template you can find in blender. But I already could solve that problem with bpy.data.window_manager[WinMan"].my_previees_weapons. thanks for you help though :D